# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: 'jpa:repositories'. 'http:// www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to do this without using Maven
    I m getting this error at this line

```
error ------Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no 
declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://
http://www.springframework.org/schem...spring-jpa.xsd', because 1) could not 
find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the 
document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Comment: I m getting this error in my xml file

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd` because points to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd`.

Change on your xml file

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

This work for me. Till guys from spring change links